# Black Yerushalmi Kippah?

Tags: minhag, clothing, chasidut-hasidism, kippa-yarmulka, yerushalayim-jerusalem

First, not talking about the Na Nach kippahs (which have different stitching and band). Those come on all kinds of colors.

I am wondering who wears a black yerushalmi kippah? Karlin-Stolin, some Breslovers, Toldos Aharon, and some Peirushim wear WHITE yerushalmi kippas, but who wears these black ones? (pic from Eichler’s).

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Whoever feels like wearing one.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen anyone wearing this. But the [Breslover webshop sells it](https://breslev.com/product/%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%94-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7-22-%D7%A1%D7%9E/) so perhaps some Breslovers wear it.

It could also be a Purim kippah.